# Alinhamento CSS + Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Estou usando o thumbnail do bootstrap porém não acho uma classe do proprio bootstrap para deixar os mesmos inline;

Estou usando [este thumbnail.](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails)

e gostaria que ele ficasse exatamente como está no exemplo;
já tentei em `<div class="row">` colocar `inline-block`, `inline` e etc e nada funciona.

Answer (score 2):

O exemplo repete uma coluna para cada imagem. Cada imagem deve estar dentro de uma div com col-md-*:

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>

   <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```